# How do you Install php-mysql on CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, centos, yum

if i try to install php-mysql I get the following error... not sure how to recover from it to get MySQL and the PHP MySQL module up and running

```
[12:51]~> yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.rocketinternet.net
 * base: mirror.san.fastserv.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.nic.uoregon.edu
 * ius: www.applesauceman.com
 * updates: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_5.4 set to be updated
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install the shared compatibility libraries package from the same place that you got the server package first.

Comment: You rock, but I have no idea where this was from, I didnt install the initial PHP or MYSQL

Comment: Try the download section of the MySQL website.

Comment: So are you saying I need like mysql51-libs.x86_64 from yum, then I can install php-mysql?

Comment: No. You need the `MySQL-shared-compat` package from the MySQL website, with the appropriate version and release to match the currently installed `MySQL-server-community` package.

Comment: Haha I dunno how to check what version I need =/

Comment: `rpm -q MySQL-server-community`

Comment: MySQL-server-community-5.1.54-1.rhel5

Comment: I found MySQL-shared-community.x86_64, but i dont see a compat one =/